# Need some explanation on OpenType tables fixed version numbers

Tags: opentype

This was extracted from [The Open Type Font File](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm) under **Version Numbers**

> Most tables have version numbers, and the version number for the
>   entire font is contained in the Table Directory. Note that there are
>   two different table version number types, each with its own numbering
>   scheme. USHORT version numbers always start at zero (0). **Fixed version
>   numbers start at one** (1.0 or 0x00010000), except where noted (EBDT,
>   EBLC and EBSC tables). Implementations reading tables must include
>   code to check version numbers so that if and when the format and
>   therefore the version number changes, older implementations will
>   reject newer versions gracefully, if the changes are incompatible.
>   When a Fixed number is used as a version, the upper 16 bits comprise a
>   major version number, and the lower 16 bits a minor. **Tables with
>   non-zero minor version numbers always specify the literal value of the
>   version number since the normal representation of Fixed numbers is not
>   necessarily followed**. For example, the version number of 'maxp' table
>   version 0.5 is 0x00005000, and that of 'vhea' table version 1.1 is
>   0x00011000. If an implementation understands a major version number,
>   then it can safely proceed reading the table. The minor version number
>   indicates extensions to the format that are undetectable by
>   implementations that do not support them.

Would appreciate some clarification on the highlighted sentences above (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's unclear about it? It's a 16 bit + 16 bit fixed length number representing a major.minor versioning number. The major version part uses "normal" encoding:

```
v1.0 = 0001.0000
v5.0 = 0005.0000
v12.0 = 000C.0000
```

And the minor version is written "literally", rather than hexadecimally:

```
v1.5 = 0001.5000
v7.16 = 0007.1600
v20.314 = 0014.3140
```